# Android Toggle Button crashes

Tags: android, audio, crash, playback, togglebutton

I am trying to make a sound to play in intervals when a toggle button is checked. After I click toggle button my app doesn't play any sound and crashes. Why?

**Code:**

```
    int bpm;
    double timetw;
    final Button plus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tempop);
    final Button minus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tempom);
    final TextView curbpm = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.curbpm);
    final ToggleButton metronomepp = (ToggleButton) findViewById (R.id.metronomepp);
    final MediaPlayer metronome = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.beep);
    bpm=60;
    timetw=((60/bpm)-0.19)*10000;
    curbpm.setText("" + bpm);

    Log.i("Metronome1", ""+metronomepp.isChecked());

    metronomepp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
             while (metronomepp.isChecked()) {
                    metronomepp.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                             Log.i("Metronome", "InWhile");
                             if (metronome.isPlaying()) {metronome.pause();}
                                metronome.seekTo(0);
                                metronome.setOnSeekCompleteListener(null);
                                metronome.start();
                                metronome.setOnCompletionListener(null)
                        }
                    }, (long) (timetw));
                }
        }
    });
```

**LogCat after I press toggle button:**

```
03-14 22:54:17.094: D/dalvikvm(25418): GC_CONCURRENT freed 101K, 3% free 9518K/9735K, paused 3ms+3ms
03-14 22:54:18.019: D/dalvikvm(25418): GC_CONCURRENT freed 5K, 2% free 9923K/10055K, paused 2ms+2ms
03-14 22:54:19.744: D/dalvikvm(25418): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 2% free 10312K/10439K, paused 1ms+1ms
03-14 22:54:23.039: D/dalvikvm(25418): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 2% free 10759K/10887K, paused 1ms+1ms
```

Comment: Can you post the Logcat?

Comment: Am I reading this right where you have `while(true)` occuring on the `CheckChangeListener` event?

Comment: Should I move while from CheckChangeListener event?

Comment: The logcat doesn't really help out any.  I would comment out the `while` statement and see if it toggles without crashing.

Comment: Commented while and it doesnt crash.

Comment: What should I do now to make it play sound?

Comment: Can you describe, what the variable ms is for? Your app isn't crashing, its freezing because of an infinite loop...

Comment: Ms indicates toggle buton state (1=checked)

Comment: There already is a variable isChecked... Why don't you use it? To play a sound in intervals, I would use a timer. The toggle button should start/stop the timer, which plays a sound on each timer tick.

Comment: I put a comment in and then turned it into an answer - see below.

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental issue you have is that you are doing a long operation in the UI thread. The onCheckedChanged should spin off a thread or Async class which will make the ticking sound until it is stopped. Better still have a thread to make the ticking sound which you turn on and off from onCheckedChanged.

Probably the best way to achieve this has been given in the answer from @Torben-Kohlmeier to your question, which I have edited to make clear how it fits with your code.

Comment: Could you please explain to me how to make another thread which is turned on and of from onCheckedChange for playing ticking sound?

Comment: @torben-kohlmeier has provided an even better answer based on the same ideas, which has been edited to fit into your question more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the use of a [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) here. With `Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)`, you can schedule a task to be run in intervals (period).
Further, you need a TimerTask. Just create a class which extends TimerTask and implement the run() method to play the metronome sound.

To give you some code examples:

1. Create the Timer in your Activity:

   ```
   class MyActivity extends Activity {
       // In the variables declared for the class:
       private Timer timer = new Timer();
       private long timerTickGapMilliseconds = 1000L; // Change this to change how often the sound is played.
   ```
2. Implement MetronomeTimerTask as a subclass of your Activity Class:

   ```
   class MetronomeTimerTask extends TimerTask {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           // play the metronome sound, from your code.
       }
   }
   ```
3. Start or Stop the Timer
   Inside your code in the question, replace onCheckedChanged:

   ```
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
       if (metronomepp.isChecked()) {
           timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MetronomeTimerTask(), 0, timerTickGapMilliSeconds);
       }
       else {
           timer.cancel();
       }
   }
   ```